How to do a proper selenium web scrape in firefox?
I am trying to do a selenium program where I am trying to do a basic web scrape where I am able to get the title of the website. Yet, whenever I try to do the most basic web scrape using selenium with all the web drivers already installed I get a bunch of errors which I can't interpret and I still can't find the solution to my problems anywhere online.
This is the code I typed into vs code:
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\geckodriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.bestbuy.com")
print(driver.title)
driver.quit()

This is the error response I received:
c:\Program Files (x86)\VS Code\Product Scalper.py:3: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\P'
  PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\geckodriver.exe"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Program Files (x86)\VS Code\Product Scalper.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(PATH)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\victo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 57, in __init__
    if finder.get_browser_path():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\victo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 47, in get_browser_path
    return self._binary_paths()["browser_path"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\victo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 56, in _binary_paths
    browser = self._options.capabilities["browserName"]
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'


With the latest version of selenium from pypi.org, selenium will automatically download and install any needed drivers for you. If your on windows, selenium will store these downloaded drivers in your user folder under \.cache\selenium. Try running your code without the PATH argument.

Use raw string for PATH like so r"C:\Program Files (x86)\geckodriver.exe". Backslashes in normal strings are used for special characters like \n. You also can use double backslashes, and it will still work e.g. "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\geckodriver.exe".

I tried both and it still doesn't work
